# How to get values from dynamically created function component in next.js

Tags: next.js, state

I have a component count. It changes. I add dynamically function component as many as count.
Then I want to get values of variables.

```
const MainComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ fields, label, addCount }) => {


const components = () => {
    
    const comps = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < addCount; index++) {
    comps.push(<CampaignConfigurationProperty fields={fields[index]} label={label}></CampaignConfigurationProperty>);
    }
    return comps;
};


return (
    <div>
    <p>{label}</p>
    <div className={styles.anotherText + " " + styles.endText + " col"}>
    {components()}
    </div>
    </div>

);
};
export default MainComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is code i think have error but this is help you !

```
const MainComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ fields, label, addCount }) => {

    const [comps , setComps] = useState<any>([])
    useEffect(() => {
       const components = () => {
         const x = []
         for (let index = 0; index < addCount; index++) {
         x.push({fild: fields[index]} ,label :label );
        }
       return comps;
       };
       setComps(components())
    },[])



return (
    <div>
    <p>{label}</p>
    <div className={styles.anotherText + " " + styles.endText + " col"}>
{comps.map((i , index) => 
    <CampaignConfigurationProperty key={index} fields={i.fild} label={i.label} />
)}
    </div>
    </div>

);
};
export default MainComponent;
```